# Excel Custom Row Number

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a table on excel:

```
     A        B         C         D        E
--------------------------------------------
1    Group    Number    Value
2    SS       001       20
3    SS       002       10
4    BN       001       30
5    GU       001       10
```

I want to have an automatic row number per "`Group`". Also, the "`Number`" column, should be automatic too. So, if I type "**SS**" on **row number 6**, then the **Number** value should be "**003**". If I type "**BN**" on **row number 7**, then the **Number** value should be "**002**".

Is there a way to do that? Really appreciated.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: What do you mean by automatic row number per "`Group`". What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have 3 kinds of Group.. "SS", "BN", and "GU". I want to have an automatic number on column B base on those groups. I do a manual thing right now. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Batman's :) formula is also correct. I added formatting to get exactly what you want.

```
=TEXT(SUMPRODUCT(--($A$2:A2=A2)),"00#")
```

Drag this formula down

Comment: I put the formula on column B? I tried it, but it said.. "Careful, we found one or more circular ref. FYI: A circular ref can be a formula that referes to its own cell value.. blah blah... It doesn't works.

Comment: Sorry, revised the formula. should have targeted column A.

Answer (score 0):

In cell B6, enter the formula `=countif(A:A,A6)` and then fill down.  That should do it for you.

Comment: i believe OP wants to increment the `Number` column everytime a new value is added. Your formula will change all values in Number column to the count of the Group. What is required is to have how many such groups are above + 1.

Comment: What about, in B2, `=Countif($A$1:$A2,A2)` and drag down?  Then just format the column to show three digits.